# Can we use alias name in LIKE statement?

Tags: mysql

I have a query to search strings from database tables. The query is

```
SELECT  id
      , (SELECT office_name
         FROM   office_master
         WHERE  office_id = wan_reports.name
        ) AS ofname
      , (SELECT City_Name
         FROM   City_Master
         WHERE  City_Id = wan_reports.location
        ) AS lname
      , wan_ip
      , (SELECT office_class
         FROM   office_master
         WHERE  office_id = wan_reports.name
        ) AS class
      , last_online
      , last_check
      , attempts
FROM    wan_reports
WHERE   1 = 1
        AND (id LIKE 'B%'
             OR ofname LIKE 'B%'
             OR lname LIKE 'B%'
            );
```

Now here `ofname` in `LIKE` statement says unknown column. Is there any way to use alias in `LIKE` statement?

Comment: Wrap it inside inline view (subquery in `FROM` ) :  `SELECT * FROM (your_query)a WHERE a.id like ... or a.ofname like ...`

Comment: You might repeat the subqueries, but they will be evaluated twice (MariaDB has subquery cache, MySQL afaik not yet). But you should rewrite that to joins, it is more performant and you can use the columns directly

Comment: See this question for the reasoning behind not being able to use your alias in the where clause.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001183/mysql-order-of-operations
It is because even though you type in that order, that is not the order that MySQL reads it.

Comment: @JoshSimar The question you linked has one incorrect and one irrelevant answer.

Comment: @ypercube If that is the case then what is the order of operations?

Comment: The logical order or processing is `FROM -> WHERE -> GROUP BY -> HAVING -> SELECT -> ORDER BY`. MySQL deviates somehow and we can use aliases in the `HAVING`. (so the order of SELECT and HAVING may be reverse).

Comment: You can use not only column aliases but values of expressions and subselects so big part of SELECT actually happens before HAVING as HAVING can see selected and ONLY selected columns: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a05ca/1

Comment: Yes, what I said, in MySQL the logical order for SELECT and HAVING is reversed. But the ONLY you say is rather wrong. All columns of the tables are visible in HAVING. This is valid for example: `SELECT t.b FROM t WHERE a=1 HAVING EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM u WHERE u.c=t.c);`

Comment: @ypercube I meant the `Unknown column 'a' in 'having clause'` from the fiddle I linked (that actually surprised me quite a bit), but you are right, "only" is not the case, will have to check why this one happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least 3 different ways to do that. I will show all of them and add a link to sqlfiddle for each, but I strongly suggest you to adopt the last one.

You can wrap the query in another query and do the filtering "one level higher":

```
select * from (
  SELECT  id
      , (SELECT office_name
         FROM   office_master
         WHERE  office_id = wan_reports.name
        ) AS ofname
      , (SELECT City_Name
         FROM   City_Master
         WHERE  City_Id = wan_reports.location
        ) AS lname
      , wan_ip
      , (SELECT office_class
         FROM   office_master
         WHERE  office_id = wan_reports.name
        ) AS class
      , last_online
      , last_check
      , attempts
  FROM    wan_reports
) tmp
WHERE   1 = 1
        AND (id LIKE 'N%'
             OR ofname LIKE 'N%'
             OR lname LIKE 'N%'
            );
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c2a3/2

You can use HAVING (it is officially not supported as HAVING is supposed to work only on aggregated values, but it works really only as late WHERE in MySQL:

```
SELECT  id
      , (SELECT office_name
         FROM   office_master
         WHERE  office_id = wan_reports.name
        ) AS ofname
      , (SELECT City_Name
         FROM   City_Master
         WHERE  City_Id = wan_reports.location
        ) AS lname
      , wan_ip
      , (SELECT office_class
         FROM   office_master
         WHERE  office_id = wan_reports.name
        ) AS class
      , last_online
      , last_check
      , attempts
FROM    wan_reports
HAVING   1 = 1
        AND (id LIKE 'N%'
             OR ofname LIKE 'N%'
             OR lname LIKE 'N%'
            );
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c2a3/6

Usually the best is using joins instead of subqueries:

```
SELECT  id
      , office_name AS ofname
      , City_Name AS lname
      , wan_ip
      , office_class AS class
      , last_online
      , last_check
      , attempts
FROM    wan_reports
JOIN  office_master on (office_id = wan_reports.name)
JOIN  City_Master on (City_Id = wan_reports.location)
WHERE   1 = 1
        AND (id LIKE 'N%'
             OR office_name LIKE 'N%'
             OR City_Name LIKE 'N%'
            );
```

- If there is a possibility that the matching office/city will not exist, then you need to change the corresponding inner join to a left join. That would return NULL in joined columns in case no match was found.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c2a3/5

Subqueries have a history of poor performance in MySQL. It is becoming better witch each new version but in the optimizer can still handle joins much better. And as you can see the join version is actually shorter for writting. You only have to use "original" columns names in WHERE even if you assign them aliases for output.

Comment: If wan_reports.name or .location could be null then you want to change those joins to left joins in the last example, and I would recommend always aliasing tables and referencing columns by table alias prefix.

Comment: @BateTech Yep, forgot to add the note about a possible left join, thanks. I did not add aliases to keep the same style OP used so they can easily match the code to the original.